# git for use on local machine only, with no cloning to/from remote machines?

Tags: security, git

On a CentOS Linux machine, developers have user accounts.  They need to be able to use git on the local machine while logged in via ssh, but is there a way to prevent them from cloning their repositories to other machines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  If a user can `ssh` to a machine and they have read permissions on a repository, they can copy the repository (using `rsync` or `scp`), and that is all that is necessary to clone a `git` repository.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's not really a git question anymore, but still a security one: could one in theory delegate the git-ing to trusted users, and set up a restricted chroot jail with an editor and some shell basics for un-trusted users?

Comment: sure, but if you want users w/ ssh access to share a DVCS repo (git/ht/etc) the best combination of easy/safe is probably to set up an account to which they all have access (maybe by RSA pub key for convenience?).  there are probably hundreds of ways to share a repo outside of ssh though.  also, would you mind clicking the check next to the question to accept it as an answer?  thnx :)

Comment: oh! of course! *click* (sorry, I'm new here.)  Being a git newb, I was overly focused on its ramifications in my scenario and completely overlooked the larger issues involving ssh and shell access. Thanks for redirecting my attention.

Comment: i'm still pretty new to git as well, the sharing options can be tough to navigate

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no. You could probably remove git-upload-pack from the system which would make this harder by making `git clone` stop working, but a simple `scp` of the entire directory would still be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

ensure other machines are not writable / accessible, but other than that no.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you get that, I did answer the question, I said no, except doing that. COuld have been phrased better but was a answer, not feedback. It was a crappy answer, as indicated by the 0 point score.

pedantic much? its like over a year old